# Ruby remove first word from string

Tags: ruby, string

i'm little struggling to find solution of this. How can i remove first word from string like my strings below.

```
     "i am going to school"

     "he is going to school"

     "she is going to school" 

     "they are going to school"
```

so string can be any string and don't know about exact length of first word.but just want to remove first word.

The result should be like below

```
      "am going to school"

     "is going to school"

     "is going to school" 

     "are going to school"
```

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
"i am going to school".split(' ')[1..-1].join(' ')

=> "am going to school"
```

You can go both ways in an array in ruby so -1 is the last element.

Comment: Or alternatively to slicing, `"i am going to school".split(' ').drop(1).join(' ')` using [Enumerable.drop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop) to skip the first element.

Answer (score 10):

`'she is going to school'[/(?<=\s).*/] => "is going to school"`

This uses Ruby's positive lookbehind anchor:

> (?<=pat) - Positive lookbehind assertion: ensures that the preceding
>   characters match pat, but doesn't include those characters in the
>   matched text

So the pattern looks for a whitespace character followed by a string of any characters. Since repetition (e.g., "*") is greedy, it selects the longest matching string.

Comment: Good answer. You could afford to be a bit more descriptive though.

Answer (score 1):

Use regexp

```
str = "i am going to school"
puts str.gsub(/^(\w\s+)(.*)/, '\2')

=> "am going to school"
```

Comment: There is no point of using `gsub` when there is at most one match per string.

Answer (score 1):

Do this for each string:

```
string.sub(/\s*[\w']+\s+/, "")
```